# scraping multiple tags at once

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the imdb top 250 movies and I want to get all the links of those movies from this page `https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/`
I tried

```
html = urlopen('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
links = []
for link in bs.find('td',{'class':'titleColumn'}).find_all('a'):
    links.append(link['href'])
print(links)
```

but I'm only getting the first link only, so my question is how to scale this code to include the whole list of 250 movies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bs.find('td',{'class':'titleColumn'})` gives you the first entry, and `find_all('a')` gives you all the `<a>` tags under that entry. To find all the entries you can use

```
for link in bs.select('td.titleColumn > a'):
    links.append(link['href'])
```

If you still want to iterate over the titles list and extract more information you need to locate all the titles and extract `<a>` from each one

```
for title in bs.find_all('td', {'class': 'titleColumn'}):
    links.append(title.find('a')['href'])
```